# Parse Json with dynamic response objective-c

Tags: ios, iphone, json

I'm having some trouble parsing the following error response to display in an UIAlertView -

```
{"error": {
"email": {
  "isEmpty": "Value is required and can't be empty"
},
"password": {
  "isEmpty": "Value is required and can't be empty"
},
"name": {
  "isEmpty": "Value is required and can't be empty"
},
"surname": {
  "isEmpty": "Value is required and can't be empty"
}
},
```

Usually I'd do something like this to get the objects inside of each dictionary but the problem is the keys will change depending on the error. How do I properly parse through this?

```
NSDictionary * Json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                  options:kNilOptions
                                                                  error:&error];
NSDictionary * error = [Json objectForKey:@"error"];
for (NSDictionary * subError in error) {
                 NSLog(@"subError = %@", subError);
             }
```

This will just print email, password, name and surname. I can do something like this but I won't always know what the second key is. In this case it's "password" -

```
NSDictionary * error = [[Json objectForKey:@"error"] objectForKey:@"password"];
```

Comment: Your first problem is that you're missing the leading `{` in the JSON listing.

Comment: Your second problem is that you haven't read the spec for NSDictionary.

Comment: Added the { and not sure what you're referring to in regard to reading the spec for NSDictionary

Comment: It means that if you read the spec you would not need to ask the question.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working with the following code -

```
NSDictionary * subError = [[luckyNumbers objectForKey:@"error"] objectForKey:[[error allKeys] objectAtIndex:0]];
title = [[error allKeys] objectAtIndex:0];
message = [[[luckyNumbers objectForKey:@"error"] objectForKey:[[error allKeys] objectAtIndex:0]] objectForKey:[[subError allKeys] objectAtIndex:0]];

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                           initWithTitle:title
                                           message:message
                                           delegate:nil
                                           cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                           otherButtonTitles:nil];
                     [alert show];
```

Answer (score -1):

You should not iterate over NSDictionnary. You should try something like :

```
NSDictionary * error = [Json objectForKey:@"error"];
for (NSString * subErrorKey in [error allKeys]) {
    NSLog(@"subError = %@", [[error objectForKey:subErrorKey] objectForKey:isEmpty]);
}
```

Comment: That makes no sense.  You're iterating over the dictionary, in spite of saying don't, and you're using the undefined value `isEmpty` for a key.

Comment: This is very similar to what I'm doing. The issue is I may not know the key "isEmpty". That could be a different key. I'm trying to see if there is a way to do this without knowing every key beforehand.